# Linked resources file (resx) with unlinked designer.cs file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a Silverlight project and a WPF project that are sharing a resource (.resx) file.
The file is in the Silverlight project and linked from the WPF project.
Since obviously the designer.cs files generated by WPF and Silverlight are not compatible, is it possible to declare the designer.cs as a local file instead of linked file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible to have a local designer.cs
But there's a workaround :

- Open the .csproj of the project holding the link
- Rename the Designer.cs file everywhere, for example MyResource.Designer.cs -> MyResourceWPF.Designer.cs
- In the original folder copy the MyResource.Designer.cs file to MyResourceWPF.Designer.cs
- In the project holding the link open the .resx file and modify it (for example if it is public change it to internal and then public again) to force a recompilation

Then you can compile any of the projects without creating errors in the other one.